# Has someone created a Notification Centre for their Mobile App?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, app, sfdcmobilesdk-android

By notification center I am referring to a **centralized location where users can view and manage all the notifications generated by the app**.

For eg - The heart icon on Instagram leads to the activity tab, which serves as Notification center.

I want to implement something similar for my App. I already have SFMC SDK installed in the app and sending Push notifications from SFMC. I wanted to understand what would be the best approach to achieve this? Should I create a DE to store the notifs? And ask the app dev team to create a UI and then API endpoints to pull the customer specific data from the DE and show?

If anyone has worked on something similar please do provide insights! Thank you!